# Shop specific Header (Logo) in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

In my Magento Shop there are two Shops, each Shop should display its own `Header image`.

How can I realize this ? In `Magento Backend, there is only the opportunity to enter a path to a single image.`

I tried to do it with static blocks. But where to implement the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your header image html is defined in the header of your theme I would edit app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/page/html/header.phtml

Find and edit the logo html with something like the following where the logo image includes the store code.

```
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="header-center header-logo">
        <img src="/media/logo/logo-shop-<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() ?>.png">
        </div>
```

Then create your logos and save them with the corresponding store codes i.e. logo-shop-1.png, logo-shop-2.png.

Comment: But the in Magento 1.9.0.1 it seems to be this part of header.pthml 
<header id="header" class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header-container">